# Magento 2 : Error The element 'product.info.main' already has a child

Tags: magento2.2

I am just working to make my Magento site run faster and I'm seeing a lot of repeated rows in my Magento2.2.2 `exception.log` file that says the below.

However, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Wondering if anyone can explain better what it means.

I have a theme I purchased and then created a child theme of the purchased theme .So, I can edit the phtml and css files to customize the theme.

```
main.CRITICAL: The element 'product.info.main' already has a child with alias 'other' {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Search all of your theme and sub-theme layout files for the following snippet:

```
as="other"
```

The error is telling you that there's two different locations that are trying to define a block or container with an alias of "other", and of course names and aliases have to be unique.